# How to stop onscreenclick() after only one click

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How to stop onscreenclick(function) after only one click(execute function only one time)?

I want to repeat that input color, execute 'drawShape' only one time, and revert color input again.

```
from turtle import*

def drawShape(x,y):    
    pensize(50)
    up()
    goto(x,y)
    down()
    goto(x,y-25)

while(1):
    color=input("input color (turn off: a)")
    if color =="a":
        break
    elif color=='red':
        pencolor("red")
        onscreenclick(drawShape)
        mainloop()
   elif color=='green':
       pencolor("green")
       onscreenclick(drawShape)
       mainloop()
   else:
       print("worng input")

print("End")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can use `onscreenclick(None)` at the beginning of `drawShape()` to turn off further clicks until enabled by user responses.

A complete solution with various style changes:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def drawShape(x, y):
    screen.onscreenclick(None)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.sety(y - 25)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.pensize(50)

while True:
    color = input("Input color (turn off = a): ")

    if color == 'a':
        break

    if color in ['red', 'green']:
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        screen.onscreenclick(drawShape)
    else:
        print("Wrong input")

print("End")
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Can I make lines remain which draw from all times drawShape? For example, the first time, I input the first color, execute drawShape ( and do not shut down turtle page ) and continue second time, input color, execute drawShape that in turtle page with first time drawShape remained.

Comment: @Jungpago, doesn't the example I provided work that way?  If not, you'll need to clarify what you're trying to do.